# mysql_ deprecated

Tags: php, mysql

I have been told that the `mysql_` extension is now deprecated in the current version of PHP and will be removed at some point.

What should I use instead of this and how?

For nearly all my queries I use it.

**For example:**

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions

Comment: you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php)

Comment: It's not just `mysql_num_rows()`.  It is _all of_ the `mysql_*()` functions, `mysql_connect(),  mysql_query(), etc...`

Comment: Chose between the PDO or MySqli libraries.

Comment: Not only `*_num_rows` is deprecated, **the entire mysql_** extension is. Read: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: WOW I pretty much have to re write everything in my current systems. Thank you guys

Comment: @OliverB You have some time to get it done, but it is unwise to write any new code with the old API.

Comment: I am also glad that my univeristy took £30k of my money to teach me functions i should not use.

Comment: Whoa! I wish a could get a hold of the lesser sum for all that *real* education I provide for thousands stackoverflow users.

Comment: @OliverB You don't have to rewrite your entire system. You can keep it as is. Just do it for new code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the `PHP` Manual, you should use any of the following:

- [mysqli_stmt_num_rows()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)
- [PDOStatement::rowCount()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

To be clear though, neither of these is a mere substitute for `mysql_num_rows()`.  Your code must eventually be rewritten entirely to use the MySQLi or PDO API in lieu of `mysql_*()`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I now use the [MySQL Improved extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

If you choose to use it in the procedural way it can be used in a very similar manner to how you're currently using the old MySQL extension.

**Example (MySQL):**

```
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

**Example (MySQL Improved):**

```
$result = mysqli_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysqli_error());

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

However, I use MySQL Improved in an object orientated manner.

More information can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: using mysqli_query() is no better than mysql_query()

Comment: @YourCommonSense mysqli_query() is not deprecated. That's the point.

Comment: Do I need to install something to make `mysqli_*` work?

Comment: @aliA You need to make sure the MySQL Improved extension is included with the package of PHP you've got.

Answer (score 1):

If you understand the idea of database abstraction libraries, use [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql)

```
$data = $db->getAll($query,$param1,$param2);
$rows = count($data);
```

If using raw API functions is more familiar to you, use [PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stm->execute(array($param1,$param2));
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
$rows = count($data);
```

Note 2 important things:

- requested data already stored in the $data variable.
- **every** dynamical query part (i.e. inserted variables) have to be inserted via **placeholder**

Comment: Thank you for your notes, very useful. PDO is now my new baby.

Answer (score 0):

Via [`php.net/mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) manual

> **mysql_num_rows**
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [`mysqli_stmt_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php)
> - [`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

Answer (score 0):

As at the offical [mysql_num_rows function description](http://de3.php.net/mysql_num_rows) mentioned you might use [Mysqli](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MYSQL](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

[don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) -this article will help you decide which.

If you choose PDO, here is a [good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)

Comment: This almost automated response is pretty annoying and doesn't properly answer the question.