# PHP Select List - Insert multiple values in database

Tags: php, mysql, selectlist, multiple-value

I'm trying to insert multiple values in the database using select list. What I got so far:

HTML

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
            <select name="cars[]" multiple="multiple" style="width:300px">
            <?php 
            $getcars = mysql_query("SELECT cars_id, cars_name FROM car");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getcars)) {
                $car_id = $row['cars_id'];
                $car_name = $row['cars_name'];
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $car_id ?>"><?php echo $car_name ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
            </select><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
        </form>
```

PHP

```
        $cars= $_POST['cars'];
        echo $cars;
        for($i = 0; $i < count($cars); $i++){
            echo $cars[$i];
            $carGroups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_groups VALUES('$company','$cars[$i]]')"); 
        }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I tried to print $cars to check the resulted value. It prints "Array", and when I tried to print $cars[$i] it prints nothing.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra closing bracket that should be removed. You are not checking if your query was successful or not.

```
$carGroups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_groups VALUES('$company','$cars[$i]]')");
```

should be:

```
$carGroups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_groups VALUES('$company','$cars[$i]')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Since $cars is an array, you can print its content using [print_r](http://php.net/print_r) or [var_dump](http://php.net/var_dump):

```
print_r($cars);
var_dump($cars);
```

Useful reading:
[How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/1409082)
[mysql_* functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15293872/1409082)

Comment: i changed it but still not working. it prints "Array" and in the database it inserts 0's

Comment: that was really useful. My mistake was a variable name (a wrong letter basically). I checked it with print_r. Now it's fine! Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have error $cars[$i]] and need change $cars[$i]

```
$carGroups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_groups VALUES('$company','$cars[$i]]')");
```

fix php for you with good sql

```
   $cars= $_POST['cars'];
    echo $cars;
    foreach($cars as $i => $cars_name){
        echo $cars_name;
        $carGroups = mysql_query("INSERT INTO car_groups SET `fieldcompany`='{$company}', `fieldcars`='{$cars_name}'"); 
    }
```