# My page is taking a long time to load and I can't get into it

Tags: php, html

I asked this question 20 minutes ago but when I inserted the code, the site takes a long time to load. I received the following error messages, 10 minutes later:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareLife\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 11  

Warning: mysql_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=2252 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareLife\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 11  

Warning: mysql_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareLife\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 11  

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareLife\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 11
```

**Using the following code:**

```
<?php
$conn_error = 'Colud not connect.';

$mysql_host = "localhost:8080";
$mysql_user = "liam";
$mysql_pass = "";

$mysql_db = 'socialnetwork';


mysql_connect($mysql_host, $mysql_user, $mysql_pass) or die("Couldn't Connect") ;
mysql_select_db('mysql_db') or die($conn_error);

echo 'Connected!';
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure 8080 is the right port for your mysql server?  That's a rather unusual port for mysql.

Comment: Not sure how related it is, but your error messages indicate that you are using the deprecated `mysql_*` extension. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293872/mysql-deprecated) for using the new `mysqli` or `PDO` extensions.

Comment: @ajp15243 Their error messages?  That could be seen by just looking at the code c.c, 1+ though.

Comment: @Daedalus Yeah I noticed that later, after seeing that the last two lines didn't have a `$` in front of the `mysql_`.

Comment: Please do not post duplicates. They only scatter people's answers and increase how much work everyone has to do. Just edit your question or post a comment.

Answer (score 6):

You are using a string as a variable:

```
mysql_select_db('mysql_db') or die($conn_error);
```

Should be:

```
mysql_select_db($mysql_db) or die($conn_error);
```

Should be × 2

```
// make your db the current db http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($mysql_db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\'t use $mysql_db : " . mysql_error());
}
```

**But REALLY should be (using PDO, change all your code):**

```
    try {
        $DB= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=socialnetwork', 'liam', '');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }
```

Comment: Worked but one error left 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '') or die($conn_error); ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ShareLife\inc\scripts\mysql_connect.inc.php on line 12

Comment: You should state it's a different extension for your expansion.. because as it is, you're providing a wrong answer for what they're using currently.

Answer (score 2):

Windows use [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) which uses localhost for better performance because of the less overhead it has.

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
```

Unix systems uses [Unix Domain Socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket)

```
$mysql_host = '127.0.0.1';
```

But apache connects to PHP using TCP/IP or Unix Domain Socket. so either way should work.

Comment: The IP-address in your second example should be within quotes, otherwise PHP will attempt to concatenate the numbers; `$mysql_host = '127.0.0.1';` Please modify your answer via the [edit] link. Also, your answer could be improved by adding some explanation so that the OP may learn something from it.